# How to display the user in comment

Tags: php, laravel

I have a comment box in my app and its working fine. but i want to display the user who comment in my post how can i achieve this? i have this code so far.

This is my view

```
<div class="view-post">
        <div class="body">
            <h3>{{$posts->title}}</h3>
            <h6>{{$posts->created_at->toFormattedDateString()}}</h6>

            <p><img src="{{ asset('img/' . $posts->image) }}" class="img-rounded"/></p>
            <p>{{$posts->content}}</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <section>
            <h5>LEAVE US A COMMENT</h5>
            <form action="{{ URL::route('createComment', array('id' => $posts->id))}}" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Comment..." name="content">        
                </div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" />
            </form>
        </section><br>

        <section class="comments">  
            @foreach($posts->comment as $comments)
            <blockquote>{{$comments->content}}</blockquote>
            @endforeach
        </section>

    </div>
```

My Controller

```
public function viewPost($id)
    {   
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $user = Auth::user();
        $this->layout->content = View::make('interface.viewPost')->with('posts', $post )->with('users',$user);

    }


public function createComment($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);


        $comment = new Comment();
        $comment->content = nl2br(Input::get('content'));


        $post->comment()->save($comment);

        return Redirect::route('viewPost', array('id' => $post->id));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model you can set up relations between one and another model.

Like that..

**User Model**

```
class User extends Model {

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

**Comment Model**

```
class Comment extends Model {

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

So you can get the user with

```
$comment = Comment::find(1);
$user = $comment->user()->get();
```

Comment: so aside from user to post and post to comment relationship i have to do this?

Comment: I guess so. Try it once like that.